# Handling mouse pointers on HTML Canvas

Tags: html, canvas, mootools

I have installed Cloudbase's FreeRDP on my machine. Post installation, I start the FreeRDP server and connect to the web interface, provide the remote machine details, I am able to see the remote desktop on my browser. The whole of the remote desktop is displayed inside a Canvas tag. Whenever the mouse pointer changes in the remote machine(based on what you point it to, it changes to loading/resize/...pointers), the cursor property in the Canvas tag changes and hence the mouse pointer changes. But the tricky part is, the wsgate.js, mootools.js don't use the browser builtin mouse pointers but generates random numbers as url parts and fetches the mouse pointer from some location that is not available on the server. I am missing out on something. Need help in understanding how this works.

The Request URL http://localhost:8000/cur/00679488/8 is the url for the cursor, but in the server directory I dont find the 'cur' folder.

Comment: Not sure I understand your problem. Do you have problems finding mouse position with MooTools, or a comunication problem between server and desktop? Can you recreate that in a iFrame environment on jsFiddle so we can check it out?

Comment: The communication between the server and desktop works fine. Infact, everything works fine. Wherever the cursor is set from the code, the code refers to some url for the cursor. This particular url is dynamically generated. I dont understand how the dynamically generated url whose corresponding path is not present in the server serve a cursor.  I am trying to setup a jsFiddle environment.

Comment: @Sergio not sure how to recreate the scenario using jsfiddle. As the scenario depends on a RDP web socket gateway server.

Comment: It's probably a route uri, intercepted internally by the server to provide a cursor image.

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Thanks.. I missed looking at it as a route uri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, also open source and based on FreeRDP, you may have a look to [Myrtille](https://github.com/cedrozor/myrtille). I tried to simplify as most as possible the mouse (including the pointer) and keyboard events handling.

The main difference over FreeRDP-WebConnect is that Myrtille is written in C# (.NET) and the gateway is hosted on IIS.

Disclaimer: I made Myrtille.